# Suppose $KA = {\bf0}$ and $K$ is idempotent. Define $G = (A-K)^{-1}$. Prove that (i) $AG = I-K$; (ii) $AGA = A$; and (iii) $AGK = {\bf0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't know how to start this one. Should I divide these into cases where $K$ is the identity matrix, the null matrix and an idempotent matrix w/c is not null and identity? Help please. Thank you.

Comment: For (i) you should replace $G$ by its definition. For (ii) and (iii), use $AG$ in (i).

Comment: Yes but A(A-K)^-1 = [(A-K)A^-1]^-1. And then what next?

Comment: I don't think it is obvious that $A-K$ is invertible at all; is that (a forgotten) part of the hypotheses?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way (with details left to be filled in!)

As $KA = 0$, we have
$$ A = A - KA - K + K^2. $$
Do you see why? The right hand side factors nicely to get (i).

Then (ii) and (iii) follow directly from using (i) and the hypotheses.

Comment: Oh I get it. Then you multiply G to both sides right? So I'd get (i). Thank you very much!

Comment: Wait, but AG = (A-K)(I-K)G = (A-K)(I-K)(A-K)^-1. Is it the same as (A-K)(A-K)^-1(I-K)?

Comment: Yes, multiply by $G$. You can write $A - KA = (I - K)A$, and similarly for the other, and you should get your second factorization.

Comment: I should add, it's good that you're being careful with not just commuting the matrix multiplication! Though on that note, be careful with pulling the $A$ off from the *right* of $KA$.